# Landscape Background with OpenGL1.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im a bit confused by the power of 2 restriction with openGLES1.0/1.1

What image size should I be using to get a decent quality landscape background for a tablet or mobile device?

I have tried 512 x 512 and 1024 x 1024, but the scaling is all wrong and image looks terrible.

Android: 1.6,1.7

Comment: What is the size of your target device(s)?

Answer (score 0):

For such purposes I usually create a texture that is just larger then the image, then use texture sub image to load the data, then create texture coordinates to fit the image.

Try doing something like this:

```
float textureWidth = 1;
float textureHeight = 1;
while(textureWidth < imageSize.width) textureWidth <<= 1;
while(textureHeight < imageSize.height) textureHeight <<= 1;
//create texture with dimensions of textureWidth x textureHeight (glTexImage2D)
//fill the data with imageSize parameters and raw data from image (glTexSubImage)
float textureCoordinateWidthRatio = imageSize.width/(float)textureWidth;
float textureCoordinateHeightRatio = imageSize.height/(float)textureHeight;
float textureCoordinates[] = {
   .0, .0,
   textureCoordinateWidthRatio, .0,
   .0, textureCoordinateHeightRatio,
   textureCoordinateWidthRatio, textureCoordinateHeightRatio
};
```

Now just use this data as you did before.

Though you did say the scaling is wrong. If by scaling you mean that ratio width/height is wrong then your problem is most likely in ether vertex array (wrong coordinates) and/or "ortho" or "viewport". In that case the above solution will have no effect. If your result is an unclear background (or blurry), this might be the solution you are looking for but it might also just be solved with texture parameters.

Comment: Thanks for that. I foudn that if I use a canvas of 1024 x 1024 and only use 480 x 800 of that canvas and then define a texture region from the texture based on the 480 x 800 only and a vector or 0,0 it seems to work fine.